How do you measure the criticality of the phase state of a dynamical system?
Does anyone know how to measure the 'critical-ness' of a dynamical system in which it's configured to allow 2nd order phase transitions? For context, I'm an undergrad ML researcher that is doing research on Reservoir Computing. I'm looking into ways to modulate dynamical systems and treat them as artificial neural networks by maintaining their critical state (I dub this process as 'Homeostasis', no one really has a term for this officially yet I think). The dynamical system's architecture is an n-dimensional hyperlattice of nodes that evolves over time (input or no input).
The most apt comparison I can give for the system are Ising models. Ising models are modeled within a grid, with spin up or spin down states. The global state of Ising models evolves over time, and produces patterns.
The most viable candidate metrics I have are Shannon Entropy and Kolmogorov-Sinai Entropy for measuring the 'temperature' of these systems, and I'm doing measures on the correlation length, structure factor, finite size scaling, fractal dimensions of subgrid states, and dynamical scaling.
I haven't found a way to tie this all together as one coherent metric though.
I'm interested to know if anyone knows papers or can point me to any interesting resources on other viable metrics for measuring the criticality of these systems.
